# Mobile SDK - iOS Native App - How to Switch user while logging out

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to programmatically switch to another user while logging out of a native iOS app built using Mobile SDK?

I'm currently doing a logout by doing

```
[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].currentUser = ([SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].allUserAccounts)[0];
```

and then re-directing back to login screen. I read somewhere that it's possible to do it directly as Mobile SDK supports multiple parallel logins but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is as follows

```
NSArray *allAccounts = [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].allUserAccounts;
        if ([allAccounts count] > 1) {
            SFDefaultUserManagementViewController *userSwitchVc = [[SFDefaultUserManagementViewController alloc] initWithCompletionBlock:^(SFUserManagementAction action) {
                [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
            }];
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:userSwitchVc animated:YES completion:NULL];
        } else {
            if ([allAccounts count] == 1) {
                [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].currentUser = ([SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].allUserAccounts)[0];
            }

            [[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager] launch];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)handleUserSwitch:(SFUserAccount *)fromUser
                  toUser:(SFUserAccount *)toUser
{
    [self log:SFLogLevelDebug format:@"SFUserAccountManager changed from user %@ to %@.  Resetting app.",
     fromUser.userName, toUser.userName];
    [self resetViewState:^{
        [self initializeAppViewState];
        [[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager] launch];
    }];
}
```

This will allow you to switch users without explicitly logging them out and logging them in again. The key here is to first check if you have more than one user logged into app.

If there is only one user, you can simply logout. If there are multiple users, you don't logout, instead you use  `SFDefaultUserManagementViewController` to switch to the other user.